# WPF - Использование CroppedBitmap в качестве заполнителя для ImageBrush

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

```
<Grid Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
    <Grid.Background>
    <ImageBrush TileMode="Tile" Stretch="None" ViewportUnits="Absolute" Viewport="0,0,32,32">
        <ImageBrush.ImageSource>
            <CroppedBitmap Source="/Confidentialllllll;component/Resources/ButtonNormal.png" SourceRect="65,13,8,8" />
        </ImageBrush.ImageSource>
    </ImageBrush>
    </Grid.Background>
</Grid>
```

В результате ошибка:

> BitmapImage has not been initialized.  Call the BeginInit method, set
>   the appropriate properties, and then call the EndInit method.

Причем просто ImageBrush можно поставить, а вот с CroppedBitmap нет.

У Image можно поставить CroppedBitmap в Image.Source (или как его), а тут (вариант через браш) - нет.

Пробовал выносить и битмап и brush в ресурсы (затем биндил через StaticResource) - не помогло.

**ВАЖНО: Сделать надо именно в XAML, т.к. понадобится для набора стилей темы (ResourceDictionary)**

Comment: Посмотрите [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/710206/206435), на этой основе можно сделать расширение для XAML

Comment: `ВАЖНО: Сделать надо именно в XAML, т.к. понадобится для набора стилей темы (ResourceDictionary)`, ResourceDictionary можно пополнять и из кода

Comment: @Андрей И где этот код будет? Очень неудобно так. У меня в этой theme - штук 10 стилей (разных контролов) и в каждом по нескольку таких Background.

Comment: Это уже другой вопрос, я вам просто предложил, раз уж в XAML не получается...